# MySQL with docker-compose ports doesn't work with network

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, lando

I am not sure if this is a bug, or a feature. But I have been running this docker-compose setup for my local development databases several months now and since I have updated Docker and Lando it stopped working.

As you can see I use it for some php sites managed with Lando. Since the last update either the `ports` or the `network` directive is not working on the MySQL container.

- If I use it with the snippet below the `ports` directive is not working. Meaning I can not connect from QueryPie on `localhost:3306`, but can connect from another lando docker container with `mysql_db` as host.
- If I comment out the `networks` directive, the `ports` directive is
  working. But the `networks` directive obviously not. Meaning I can connect from QueryPie on `localhost:3306`, but I can not connect from another lando docker container with `mysql_db` as host.

Before the update they worked nice together. So I could open MySQL in QueryPie and access the databases from the Lando containers.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_db
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    ports: 
        - "3306:3306" 
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - lando_bridge_network
networks:
  lando_bridge_network:
    external: true
```

My docker engine is 19.03.8 and my docker-compose version is 1.25.5.

Comment: You've shown two database configurations; where are the clients to these databases running?  What's the actual problem you're encountering?  The `postgres` container is on the Compose-provided `default` network and not the external network, is that a problem for you?

Comment: No that is actually not a problem. The postgres container is available for the host and doesn't need to be available for other docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by removing the `networks` directive and only exposing port 3306 with `ports`. The PHP sites running on lando/docker I the internal docker IP to connect:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'host.docker.internal');
```

In QueryPie (running on the host) I can connect with `localhost:3306`

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_db
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    ports: 
        - "3306:3306" 
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```